# Laravel Class DB is not looping

Tags: database, laravel-5

When I use Laravel DB as an alternate to Eloquent, The data I get from the DB class is not looping and I have to convert it into an array but this is not working. Here is my code:

```
$result = DB::table('assets')
    ->join('locations', 'location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
    ->orWhere('state', 'LIKE', '%' . $state . '%')
    ->orWhere('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $state . '%')
    ->orWhere('city', 'LIKE', '%' . $city . '%')
    ->select('assets.*', 'locations.*')
    ->get();
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you have ? Is your query generates error or returns no result ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The query run very fine but in the view and cant loop over it like eloquent.

Comment: Check what is the structure of $result after querying the data, is it in Collection? or a plain Array? or Object ?
Give more details here by giving problems information.
I get it that you cannot loop like `foreach($result as $singleResult)` , but check by `dd($result)` before passing to the view.

Comment: @FahimUddin it return null. When i make a research the $result is returning a class with the data, not just the data alone.
Thanks

Comment: @BadmusKaybee If it is returning null then the problem is with the query. and what do you mean by research?, if the query is running then it will give you one of the 3 things, object, collection or array, you can't get a class. Please elaborate how you are doing research here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making few researches i notice that the DB class wrap it data arround a class to achive simplicity i converted the DB to eloquent.
These is my new query

```
 $result = Asset::
                    join('locations', 'location_id', '=', 'locations.id')'asset_images.id'), 'asset_images.*'
                    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                    ->orWhere('state', 'LIKE', '%' . $state . '%')
                    ->orWhere('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $state . '%')
                    ->orWhere('city', 'LIKE', '%' . $city . '%')
                    ->select('assets.*', 'locations.*')
                    ->get();
```